# How market makers exit their position?

Tags: market-making

A market maker needs to quote a bid and ask whatever its vision on the stock is. But what happens in the case of panic-selling on a particular stock?

The market maker is thus going to  buy a lot of this stock. To offset its loss it's going to hedge its position. Yet if the stock never recovers, what does the market maker does with its inventory of that stock? Is it going to keep forever hopping that the stock will recover or it will decide to accept loosing money and sell the stock?

Comment: There's a saying, "Market making is like picking up pennies in front of a steamroller". An important aspect of market making is inventory management, the purpose of which is to avoid situation you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to think about it. If there is a sell-off in a stock (or any asset class), it precisely means that there are no bids (or the bids are much lower and in very small volume from the ask) - so the value of the stock starts a descending spiral, where the seller's offers keep getting lower until they find a bid. Hence very little trading is actually taking place.

Effectively, what this means is that market-making (as you describe it) ceases during a sell-off - that's essentially the definition of a sell-off. So, the drop in liquidity and the low bids mean market participants (entering the stock post sell-off) are not accumulating material longs in the stock during the sell-off (which they subsequently would have to sell if the stock doesn't recover), thereby minimizing their losses.

Thinking about things this way, the only real losers in such a situation are the stock holders who were long prior to the sell-off. And these usually tend to be the (unhedged) speculators (who don't make markets), not the (hedged) market-makers.

Comment: But MM need to quote bid and ask whatever their vision on the stock is. So if everyone is selling they need to send bid right? They can't just say: we think the stock is going to go down so we don't send bids. Like the way I understand it is MM are neutral so whatever their vision on the stock is if a lot of people want to sell they need to buy basically

Comment: Yes, they send a bid, and it isn't very good, and its in small size. Some price-takers consider it too bad a bid and don't trade it, and then its lower then next time. You seem to have the view that market-makers are required to knowingly show liquidity which is guaranteed to make them a loss (i.e. show bids that are too high in too large quantities). They aren't and they don't.  There will occasionally be times when market-makers are caught in positions they struggle to liquidate and suffer a loss but this is a part of running the business in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Inventory management is a key element for any strategy. To qualify for any MM rewards your bids and asks are neutral. That doesn’t mean you’re required to have orders executed. Any quality system will monitor the broader market for emergency exit conditions. It’s not a casual thing to do and unlike anything else.

Look up Hummingbot for a platform tailored for this.